# I don't understand what happens on file.exists() for android on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, hashmap

i am creating an application for android in eclipse.
i have a chat application in which user's contact's images are downloaded in `sdcard` and are put in a `HashMap` `(url, localAddress)`, when i want to load contact list, for any contacts I use a function to find address of contacts' pictures on `sdcard`, three different state may occur 
1- image found on `sdcard` then return path.
2- image don't download before and `HashMap`  return null, then download it.
3- `HashMap` return a path but user deleted image from `sdcard` then remove `key` from `Hashmap` and download again.

my code:

```
public static String findFile(Context ctx, String url, String type)
{
    try
    {
        String value = globalVars.addresses.get(url);
        if(value != null)
        {
            File ff = new File(value);

            if(ff.exists())
                return value;

            globalVars.addresses.remove(url);
        }
        globalVars.enqueueJob(ctx, new globalVars.downloadJob(url, url, type));
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Find File", "Start");
        Log.e("Find File", ex.toString());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

but when i delete an image it download more and more .

function `enqueueJob` :

```
    public static void enqueueJob(Context context, downloadJob dj)
{
    if(inQueue.get(dj.getAddress())!= null && inQueue.get(dj.getAddress())== true)
        return;
    downloads.add(dj);
    inQueue.put(dj.address, true);
    FileUtils.doDownload(context);
}
```

It work's fine for pictures don't download yet and pictures that download and don't delete yet.

Comment: What does inQueue.get() return? Don't compare with both null and true.  Compare only with null if it returns a String. If it returns a boolean then use true. That it compiles...

Comment: inQueue is a `hashmap<String, boolean>` which can return for a request `null` if not exists or a boolean.

Comment: When does it return a boolean?

Comment: Maybe remove(url) does not remove. And you do not show wenn and where you how add().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title is confusing as it indicates you suspect the File.exists as the problem. Looking at your code, the fact that deleted images are added to download queue means File.exists works fine at least the first time. Otherwise, you would not even add it to the queue. Now the question is what happens when it is added to queue and downloaded. Check your code to make sure that it added back to the map properly. In your code, something should be added to the download queue only under two conditions: one if nothing in the map and the other is whatever in the map is deleted. So either it is not added back properly or may be a race condition where your File.exists is happening before the download is completed fully and you are adding it back to the queue again.

Good luck.

Comment: i update map but at a place it change to wrong value.

Comment: the picture that is deleted by user from sdcard, in map has an address when i download it again, locale map item update to new address. after it i save map to database and before save, load database to map. at this point item value changes to latest value that is wrong.